# Why is there no need for the concurrent hashmap to lock on read?

Tags: java

Why is there no need for the concurrent hashmap to lock on read?

How does Concurrent Hash Map handle multi-threading during reads?

Answer (score 0):

Any variable(object) at any point of time should be in just one state.Locks are used to prevent assigning multiple states to a variable.

Read operation will never alter the state of the variable, instead it simply fetches the state of the variable (object) at that point of time.